# How to know how to pronounce an "-e" ending based on spelling?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I’ve always wondered how the *-e* word ending should  be pronounced:

1. For example (correct me if I’m wrong), the words *apache*, *Adobe*, *Skype*, etc. have the *-e* ending pronounced like in the word *be*.
2. However (again, correct me if needed), the words *bite*, *Cheyenne*, *Bourne* have a silent *-e* at the end.

Is there a way to guess the pronunciation, or do you just **need** to know it?

Comment: I think *Skype* has a silent *-e* just like *bite*. *"Sky-Pe"* sounds really weird to me.

Comment: I don't pronounce the tailing -e in Skype. For me it rhymes with _type_, _hype_, & _snipe_. I cringe whenever I hear "sky pee".

Comment: Then I have to remember who told me to pronounce it Skypee and slap him in the face

Comment: Oh, well, almost everyone here in Taiwan pronounces it as "sky pee", so prepare yourself for 23 million slaps.

Comment: As a non-native English learner, I know "recipe" will be pronunced "recipee".

Comment: "Apache" and "adobe" are Native American words, probably adopted first by Spanish speakers and then imported into English.  My recollection of high school Spanish (it's been about 50 years) is that all vowels are pronounced. On the other hand, "Cheyenne" (with a silent `e`) is also Native American, so my best guess would be that it was imported via French.  (Just a guess on that, though.)  In general, when a word is not clearly an "import", the trailing `e` is not pronounced.  But there are many exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ‘e’ of *Skype* is not pronounced. In *apache and Adobe* it’s pronounced /i:/, that is, like the vowel sound in ‘sea’. The pronunciation of proper nouns cannot be predicted, but in common nouns, a terminal ‘e’ often indicates the way in which a preceding vowel is to be pronounced. The ‘e’ of *bite*, for example, shows that it is pronounced differently from *bit*.

Answer (score 5):

There is no hard and fast rule for pronunciation of any English words.  Pronunciation also varies regionally, so not only do you just have to know how to pronounce each word, you just have to know how to pronounce it in each part of the world in which you find yourself.

For example, the *U* in *jaguar* is pronounced like a long *U* in the UK whereas it is pronounced like a *W* in North America.

Comment: Couple that with the fact that English has loanwords from many other languages and you've really got a confusing mess on your hands if you're just learning.

Comment: @Marcus_33 - Quite right.  I certainly don't envy people trying to learn English as a second (or subsequent) language.  It has to be extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I, a nonnative speaker, would pronounce *Skype* like *Sky* with a trailing *p* = *sky - p*. That leaves *a - pa - che* and *a - do - be* as words with a pronounced *-e*.

All other words have less than three syllables, so I would keep the *-e* silent.

However, the silent *-e* clearly has its sense: see *bit* vs. *bite*.

Comment: But contrast sky v Skye.

Comment: "Less than three syllables"? If you didn't *know* Adobe was pronounced as three, it could be two (with a silent e).

Comment: That's true, "a - dobe" can be pronounced with two syllables, thus leaving the "-e" silent. But to me, it seems logical, to pronounce the "-e" in words, that have three or more syllables. What do you think?

Comment: You have to look at the source language whence we derive *Apache* and *adobe* for them to make sense: Spanish.  No silent *e*.

Comment: There are far too many exceptions in both directions for the less-than-three-syllables thing to be a useful guide. Psyche, mole (sauce), mate (tea), latte, cafe; variate, revive, analyse, compute, assume. And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues.

1) Names have an extra <e> to distinguish them from lexical words. Or you can say that these English names came from an era where final <e> was pronounced; and that these spellings have not changed.

> Low vs. Lowe's home improvement stores
>   win vs Wynne Godley (Cambridge Economist)
>   row vs Nick Rowe
>   crown vs Crowne Plaza
>   born vs Bourne Shell
>   berk vs Edmund Burke
>   brown vs Browne
>   town vs Towne
>   west vs Weste
>   lock vs John Locke
>   keen vs Keene
>   wane vs Wayne
>   took vs John Tooke
>   wolf vs Wolfe

Other times, you can see a geminated consonant digraph to distinguish from a lexical word. You can also provide another ad hoc explanation that geminated consonants close syllables with historically short vowels.

> or vs Orr 
>   star vs Starr 
>   car vs Carr
>   bar vs Barr
>   grim vs Grimm

2) Words with a bit of foreignisms.

> **Japanese**: karate
>   **Spanish**: coyote, adobe, abalone, guacamole, machete, tamale, apache
>   **French**: cliche, resume, café, saute, forte, passe, protege,canape, toupee, touche,  Renee, Rene 
>   **Italian**: provolone
>   **Greek**:  hyperbole, epitome, acme, sesame, catastrophe, apostrophe, syncope, apocope, Aphrodite, Nike, Penelope, Calliope, Terpsichore, Gethsemane, Persephone, Tempe 
>   **Latin**: anemone, simile, recipe, acne, agave, extempore 
>   **Portuguese**: curare

Some of these French ones may have <é> instead of <e>.

**Places/Names:**

> Barre, VT
>   Boise, ID (vs. Boise, OK)
>   Duarte, CA
>   Elbe, WA
>   Lac Courte, WI
>   San Jose, CA (vs. San Jose, IL)
>   Tempe, AZ
>   Tulare, CA 
>   Yosemite National Park, CA
>   Penske Truck Rental
>   Ryan Lochte, Olympic Swimmer
>   Ben Bernanke, Fed Chairman

Comment: The French *forte* should have a silent 'e' on the end. (At least, it does in French.)

Comment: It does, though in English people tend to pronounce it the same way as the (Italian) musical term "forte".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not English speaker but I know that "Skype" will always be pronounced 'skayp'.
I noticed here that "Adobe" is not pronounced 'eydawb' but otherlike what makes me a bit shocked.

Comment: Believe it or else, ***adobe* is pronounced precisely at it is spelled!** You non-native learners of English should be pleased by this happy turn of events, one for which you have no one less to thank than His Illustriousness, the Marqués del Valle de Oaxaca himself: don Hernán Cortés Monroy Pizarro Altamirano.

Comment: @tchrist Happy? Surely it’s a pain in the back side that finally when you think you’ve figured out what those damn e’s at the end of words do and how it works, along comes this word just to prove you wrong and stick its tongue out at you!