# Is there an etymological explanation for the silent ‘g’ in “paradigm”?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, greek, silent-letters

Whenever I come across the word ***[paradigm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paradigm)***, I have to make a small conscious effort not to pronounce the letter ‘g’.

In Italian, it is spelled *[paradigma](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/paradigma)* and each letter is individually pronounced i.e. /pa·ra·dìg·ma/. But in English, *paradigm* is pronounced *paradime*, which is written phonetically as /**ˈparədʌɪm**/
(You can hear its pronunciation in this [Oxford Dictionary video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvNH_hj2D8))

Its etymological roots are Greek; παράδειγμα (**parádigma**/**parádeigma**) meaning *pattern*, *model*, *precedent*, *example*, *instance*, and from   παραδείκνυμι (paradeiknynai) meaning *show*, *present*, *compare/confront*.

However, I could find no explanation as to why the letter ‘g’ is silent nor why the letter ‘a’ was dropped.

I know in English there are many, many words that have silent letters. For example, the silent ‘e’ in *minute*, *mouse*, *goose*, *have*, etc. is a vestige of Old and Early Middle English when the suffix denoted whether a word was a noun or an adjective, singular or plural, or if it was the subject of a sentence or an object. The ‘h’ was pronounced in the middle of a word in Old English and its spelling changed to ‘gh’ in Middle English when it was preceded by a vowel. Eventually, the ‘h’ sound was dropped but its peculiar spelling still persists in words such as *night*, *sight* and *thought*.

If we look at the etymology of the term *[phlegm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phlegm)* (which also ends with ‘gm’) we find

> “Middle English *fleem*, *fleume*, from Old French *fleume*, from late Latin *phlegma* ‘clammy moisture (of the body)’, from Greek *phlegma* ‘inflammation’, from *phlegein* ‘to burn’. The spelling change in the 16th century was due to association with the Latin and Greek.”

Was there a similar change in spelling for *paradigm*? I didn't find anything. And why the /ʌɪ/ sound and not /ɪ/?

Other words of Greek origin such as ***gn***omon, ***gn***ostic, and ***gn***osis the ‘g’ is silent but in *pro**gn**osis*, the ‘g’ is instead pronounced.

Similarly,  the letter ‘g’ in ***paradigmatic*** is pronounced
 /[parədɪɡˈmatɪk](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paradigmatic)/ or [/ˌpær.ə.dɪɡˈmæt.ɪk/](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paradigmatic) (BrEng) and /ˌper.ə.dɪɡˈmæt̬-/ (AmEng). Phonetic transcriptions courtesy of Cambridge Dictionary
<sub>(I don’t understand what happened to the missing k symbol in the American transcription but you can definitely hear it in the audio.)</sub>

- Why was the last letter ‘a’ in the Greek word *parádeigma* omitted in English?
- Why is the letter ‘g’ in *paradigm* (paradime) silent but not in *paradigmatic*?

Sources
[Why is "night" spelled with "gh"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148027/why-is-night-spelled-with-gh)
[Silent "e" at the end of words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296222/silent-e-at-the-end-of-words)
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/Nouns

Comment: Only a comment, as I haven't got a full answer; but words borrowed from Greek often omit a final case ending, especially words with the nominalising suffix _-ma_, and especially words that were borrowed into English a long time ago. Examples: _chrism_, _chasm_, _orgasm_ , _phlegm_, and lots of words ending in _-ism_.  Some borrowings retain the _-a_, for example _dogma_ , _stigma_.  _Phlegm_, mentioned above, is another example where the g is silent

Comment: Re: "I don't understand what happened to the missing k symbol in the American transcription": The hyphen at the end of the transcription means "the rest is the same as in the previous transcription(s)". (Such a hyphen can also be used at the *start* of a transcription.)

Comment: Note that the Ancient Greek verb (in the dictionary form) would be transcribed as *paradeiknymi* or *paradiknymi*, not *-nai*.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is there a reason why “gn” in “reigning” is pronounced /n/ while in “regnant” it is pronounced /gn/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150937)

Comment: Perhaps “ensign”, “sign” and “signal” are equally relevant. See also “align” (and “malign” and “benign” (but “malignant”)), “arraign”, “bologna” (and “lasagna”), “campaign”, “foreign” and “sovereign” — but (in a quick search) I couldn’t find any other word where “G” is silent before “M”.

Comment: *Why is the letter ‘g’ in paradigm (paradime) silent but not in paradigmatic?* -> Quite simply, the *gm* in 'paradigmatic' is followed by a vowel which splits it up into two separate syllables; the g becomes a part of one syllable and m becomes a part of another so the g is not silent while in 'paradigm', there's no vowel that follows the *gm* so the *g* is elided because 'gm' is not an allowed syllable coda in English.  (I saw this question in your fav ones in your profile :)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul but the "g" could easily have remained silent in *paradigmatic* as in /parədʌɪmatɪk/.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, It's because of the phenomenon called [**trisyllabic laxing**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing).  *Tense vowels (long vowels or diphthongs) become lax (short monophthongs) if they are followed by two syllables, the first of which syllable is unstressed*. (No way! I also discovered the answer to my question I asked a few days ago.)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul an explanation worthy posting in an answer

Comment: You're right, it really should be spelled "paradisme".

Comment: Hilarious! 

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With *paradigm* and *paradigmatic*, just as with *phlegm* and *phlegmatic*, English only allows that *g* to be sounded when you can split a syllable. (The unassimilated version with a final *‑a* technically does still exist, but the OED calls it “rare”.)

This is all because the [***phonotactics***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics) of English (the rules for how one can arrange its phonemes) do not permit a /g/ followed by a nasal at the end the word. You see the same thing occurring with *diaphragm*, or for that matter with the simpler *phlegm*, about which the OED writes that:

> The *g* has probably never been pronounced except in disyllabic forms in *‑a*.

Indeed, this same thing happens with ***all*** the words with a *g* and a nasal at their end, including
*align,
apophthegm/apothegm,
arraign,
assign,
benign,
campaign,
consign,
deign,
design,
diaphragm,
ensign,
feign,
foreign,
hypodigm,
malign,
phlegm,
reign,
resign,
sign,
sovereign,
syntagm*.

None of those is pronounced with a /g/, and probably never has been in English. At most they once had a /ɲ/ sound there way back when they ended with an unstressed vowel that we no longer write, all thanks to French.

When these words came into English, standard spelling did not yet exist. Many passed through French, where they were written with a final *‑e*, or were modelled after words that were. French for example has *paradigme*, *diaphragme*. And words with a final unstressed *‑e* like those came to be written without it once it stopped being said, at which point there was no chance to put the /g/ in one syllable and the nasal is the next.

You might as well ask **why the *g* is “silent” in the Italian city of *Bologna***, pronounced of course with a geminated or “long” /ɲ/ in Italian or as /nj/ in English. In Italian, just as in French, the wheels of time have ground it down so that the ‹gn› spelling is now a digraph (a two-letter combo) representing /ɲ/, not as two separate letters each with their own sound.

Notice how that same thing happens with the French region of *Bourgogne* (*Burgundy* in English). Even when it’s spelled *Borgogna* in Italian, nobody “says” that *g* in French or Italian. It’s got a /ɲ/ phoneme there, which is why the Spanish sensibly spell it *Borgo**ñ**a* to avoid confusing people.

We tend to keep the written ‹g› in English words like this, even though we “can’t” say it there at the end of the word right before that final nasal. This helps us understand the shared relationship with longer words like *paradigmatic* that have a vowel after the nasal, which allows the /g/ to “reappear”. But we probably no more ever said it in *paradigm(e)* than we ever said it in *phlegm*. Our phonotactic rules forbid it.

This likely also explains why *apophthegm* from Greek *ἀπόϕθεγμα* is more often spelled *apothegm* these days. We can’t say a lot of those letters, so we’ve given up writing them.

In comments, someone asked why *aligning* doesn’t cause the /g/ to “reappear” in split syllables as it seems to with *paradigmatic* (cf. French *paradigmatique*). The answer is that *‑ing* is an **English** verbal inflection not a Classical or Romance one, but *align* the verb came to us from Middle French *alinher*, now¹ spelled *aligner* in Modern French. That means ther was never a /g/ phoneme for anyone there historically the way there was in the Greek *παραδειγματικός*. Part of the real, spoken language, our *‑ing* verbal inflection in English is 100% regular with zero exceptions, so it cannot produce something out of nothing.

In comments, the asker further inquired as to whether the word went through a bunch of different spellings historically the way *phlegm* did, and why the last syllable has a diphthong:

> “Middle English *fleem*, *fleume*, from Old French *fleume*, from late Latin *phlegma* ‘clammy moisture (of the body)’, from Greek *phlegma* ‘inflammation’, from phlegein ‘to burn’. **The spelling change in the 16th century was due to association with the Latin and Greek**.” was there a similar change in spelling for *paradigm*? I didn't find anything. And why the /ʌɪ/ sound and not /ɪ/?

The answer to these questions is that *paradigm* didn’t show up in English until hundreds of years after the word we now spell as *phlegm* did. For *paradigm*, the first actual English citation (rather than Latin) is from 1493 in Caxton, written *paradygmes* and translating French.

And the reason it’s today pronounced [ˈpæɹədʌɪm] or [ˈpeɹəˌdɑɪm] with a diphthong in the last syllable is because the [***Great Vowel Shift***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift)² notoriously changed the “long” *i* sound /iː/ into a diphthong.  English spelling was more or less frozen **before** the GVS, which explains a great deal of confusion compared with the standard Latin values for vowels that everyone else but us uses.

---

#### Footnotes

1. Because the ‹nh› and ‹gn› digraphs represent the same /ɲ/ phoneme under different orthographic traditions. Old Occitan / Provençal, being *langues d’oc*, used ‹nh› for it, as does Catalan which is also in that group. The Galician–Portuguese language deliberately broke from Castilian orthographic habits and instead adopted ‹nh› during the early 1300s thanks to the famous poet Dinis I, king of Portugal and the Algarve, because of the prestige position which the troubadours’ tongue held in that age. In contrast, the “langues d’oïl” branches of French, of which Modern French is a descendant, used the ‹gn› digraph just like Modern Italian does for this /ɲ/ sound. Castilian and Asturian use ‹ñ› (earlier ‹nn›) for the same /ɲ/ sound in those languages as the ‹nh› and ‹gn› digraphs do in theirs. Uncountably many research papers and scholarly tomes have been written about the origin of the palatalized nasal [ɲ] and lingual [ʎ] sounds during the transition from Latin to Modern Romance, no matter the spelling.
2. The GVS was a chain shift that reassigned new sounds to all the long vowels in English in a bizarre way that all other users of the Latin alphabet forevermore hate us for. :)

Comment: “Middle English *fleem*, *fleume*, from Old French *fleume*, from late Latin *phlegma* ‘clammy moisture (of the body)’, from Greek *phlegma* ‘inflammation’, from phlegein ‘to burn’. **The spelling change in the 16th century was due to association with the Latin and Greek**.” was there a similar change in spelling for *paradigm*? I didn't find anything. And why the /ʌɪ/ sound and not /ɪ/?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, *paradigm* is new; the first actual English citation (rather than Latin) is from 1493 in Caxton, written *paradygmes* and translating French. The reason it’s today pronounced /ˈparədʌɪm/ or /ˈpɛrəˌdaɪm/ is because the Great Vowel Shift changed long-*i* (so /i:/) into the diphthong all other users of the Latin alphabet forevermore hate us for. :) English spelling was more or less frozen **before** the GVS, which explains a great deal of confusion compared with the standard Latin values for vowels.

Comment: Another case of the GVS. Now I'm happy, paradoxically.

Comment: To avoid misapprehension: apothegm and apothem are both pertinent examples, but they are different words. An apothegm is a pithy saying. A regular polygon's apothem is the distance from the centre to the midpoint of a side.

Comment: Would you explain why we don't split words like _aligning_ into _a-lig-ning_?

Comment: I've incorporated the comment into the original question. I decided against bolding but the citation is identical, and so are my two requests.

Comment: @CJDennis Because there is no more a /g/ in *align* than there is in *sing*: those aren’t there. I’ve now answered your question in the main post: it’s because you can’t resurrect some sound that was never there to start with through the addition of a 100%-regular inflection used naturally in the real language, which is the spoken language not the written one, and so is unaware of Greek spellings or Romance traditions since it happens even in completely illiterate speakers, too. But this is getting far too long, so if you have a new question, I encourage you to ask it in a separate post.

Comment: Best answer of this site!

Answer (score 12):

#### Why it isn't spelled with "a"

As tchrist mentioned, the lack of final "a" is probably based, at least in part, on the change of Latin word-final "a" to French "e" /ə/, and the loss of word-final /ə/ in the latter part of Middle English.

#### Why "paradigm" isn't pronounced with /gm/

The word "paradigmatic" is pronounced with /g.m/ in separate syllables; this isn't possible in the word "paradigm", where the "m" is word-final. I would say that the phonotactic constraint that tchrist mentioned can be described as a ban on /gm/ as a coda (syllable-final) consonant cluster.

I'm not sure exactly how to explain why English speakers used /m/ rather than something like /gm̩/ as a way of getting around this ban (compare and contrast the treatment of *-sm* and *-thm* words), but it seems plausible that the use of g as a "silent" letter in older words was a factor. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Other_initial_cluster_reductions) says that the simplification of word-initial /gn/ to /n/ occurred somewhere around the 17th century, so words like *gnostic* and *gnosis* may not have been an influence until fairly late, but I believe words like *sign* that come from French and are spelled with the digraph *gn* that is used in French to represent the palatal nasal /ɲ/ had g-less pronunciations from the beginning in English.

#### The pronunciation of the vowel in the final syllable

There is actually an alternative pronunciation of "paradigm" with the "short i" sound in the last syllable. It seems to be uncommon nowadays, but I have the impression that it was more common in the past. I'm not sure that we can be confident about tracing the pronunciation with the "long i" sound back to Middle English.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=paradigm) lists both pronunciations as follows: "păr**′**ə-dīm′, -dĭm′".

Walker's *[Critical Pronouncing Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n400/mode/2up/search/paradigm)* (1791) gives the pronunciation as "pa⁴r′a⁴-di²m", where "a⁴" is described as the vowel in "fat" and "i²" is described as the vowel in "pin". The lack of vowel reduction in the second syllable may be an artificial artefact of Walker's transcription habits, but it's nevertheless clear that this indicates a pronunciation with "short i" in the final syllable. Walker compares the pronunciation to that of other words ending in "-gm" in some other places (e.g. rule #389 in the initial section laying out principles and patterns of English pronunciation, and in the entry for *impugn*).

Charles Harrington Elster's *[Big Book of Beastly Mispronunciations](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtojrMr0Ft4C&pg=PA366)* (2nd edition, 2005) summarizes the sources he looked at by saying

> PAR-uh-dim is the traditional pronunciation in both England and the United States; it was preferred by Walker (1791), Worcester (1860), Funk & Wagnalls *Standard* (1867), and the *Century* (1914). Sometime before 1900 the variant PAR-uh-dym gained currency and was sanctioned as an alternative by *Webster's Collegiate* (1917), Phyfe (1926),  *OED 1* (1928), and Vizetelly (1929), and preferred by Fowler (1926). *Webster 2* (1934) preferred -dim and labels -dym "especially British," but subsequent sources listed -dym without comment, and current dictionaries — with the exception of OED 2 (1989) — list PAR-uh-dym first. *Everyday Reader's* (1985) favors -dim, but other recent authorities — including Lass & Lass (1976), the *NBC  Handbook* (1984), Barnhart (1988), Jones (1991), and Burchfield (1996) — prefer -dym, and *WNW Guide* (1984) says that "fewer and fewer people are saying PAR uh dim." For what it's worth, I am one of them.
>
> *Second edition update:* I'm changing my tune. PAR-uh-dim is dead. Two of the six major current American dictionaries don't even bother to list it, and *ODP* (2001) gives PAR-uh-dym as both the British and American pronunciation. The -dym has come; I'm going with the flow.

(p. 366)